# Consultar variables de la clase padre desde la clase hija

Tags: c++

Esta seria mi clase padre

```
#ifndef EMPLEADO
  #define EMPLEADO
  #include<string>
  using namespace std;
 class Empleado{
private:
    string nombre;
    int empleado;
public:

    Empleado();
    Empleado(string,int);
    void setNombre(string);
    void setEmpleado(int);
    string getNombre();
    int getEmpleado();
    ~Empleado();
    };
   #endif

  #ifndef MOZO
  #define MOZO
  #include "VentaLocal.h"
  #include "Empleado.h"
  #include "Mesa.h"
  using namespace std;

  class Mozo:public Empleado{
public:
    Mozo();
    Mozo(string,int);
    int getEmpleado();
    string getNombre();
   
    ~Mozo();
   };
  #endif
```

///////////
En el Mozo.cpp

```
    int Mozo::getEmpleado(){
     
       return Empleado::getEmpleado();

   }
```

El problema es que no me imprime el nombre ni el id;
Me imprime ese numero raro que no se que es.
Tambien probe poner el string nombre y int empleado de Empleado en la parte publica para poder llamarlo desde Mozo pero no funciona tampoco
[image: El problema es que no me imprime el nombre ni el id; Me imprime ese numero raro que no se que es.]

Comment: ¿Tal vez quisiste decir `int Unidad::getPrecio()`?

Comment: si si perdon  ya lo modifique

Comment: Entonces,  ¿lo que no funciona?

Comment: Modifico el caso de arriba que tengo otro ejemplo pero con el mismo problema pero el codigo esta mas limpio que el de productos Tengo los mismo donde es una clase padre llamada Empleado y clases derivada llamada Mozo y Repartidor.

Comment: Ya modifique...

Comment: No necesitas ni redeclarar ni redefinir `getEmpleado` ni `getNombre`.  Al hacerlo en `Mozo`, escondes las definiciones en `Empleado`. Además, funciones miembro que no modifican el estado del objeto deben declararse como `const`: `int getEmpleado() const;`.  Otra consideración que debes tener es si debes declarar el destructor de las clases hijas como `virtual`.  Por ejemplo, `virtual ~Mozo();` La razón es que SOLAMENTE necesitas un destructor virtual si vas a usar `delete` en objetos polimórficos: 
`Empleado* p = new Mozo(...); delete p;`
Espero te ayude.

Comment: No podemos reproducir  tu problema, necesitamos [un ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Una nota al margen, si no tienes funciones virtuales in tu hierarquía de clases, probablemente no lo estás haciendo bien.

Answer (score 0):

Esta llamada esta bien.

```
void Unidad::getPrecio(){
    return Producto::getPrecio()
}
```

El problema es que el método `getPrecio` es privado, y solo accesible desde la propia clase `Producto`, pero no desde una clase hija.

Si quieres que sea accesible desde otros puntos del programa debes declarar el método como público o protegido, dependiendo de tus necesidades.

En tu caso, el modificador más adecuado sería `protected`, ya que permite acceder a ese método desde la clase que lo declara y desde cualquiera que herede de ella.

También, ten en cuenta que las palabras clave en C++, como los especificadores de acceso (`public`, `private`, etc), deben escribirse en minúscula, por lo que en la declaración de la clase base, debes ponerlo como te he indicado.

```
class Producto {
    public:
        // Atributos y métodos públicos
    protected:
        // Atributos y métodos protegidos
};
```

Por último, creo que las visibilidades las has puesto al revés. No sé si a propósito. Pero no es buena práctica que los atributos de instancia de una clase tengan visibilidad pública (aunque es totalmente legal hacerlo). Al contrario, lo normal es que los atributos de instancia sean privados (o protegidos si hay herencia), y los métodos que los manipulan sean públicos (incluido constructor y destructor), para respetar el principio *No hables con extraños* (ley de Demeter).

Una última cosa, con la que siempre debes tener mucho cuidado porque los compiladores a veces se vuelven un poco locos y muestran un montón de fallos: tras la definición de la clase `Producto`, que cierras con una llave `}` te falta agregar un punto y coma, quedando `};`.

Comment: Perdon es que cuando lo escribi aca lo puse al reves ya lo modifique los atributos es en privado y las operaciones publicas. Yo lo puse asi por que en mi modelo hay dos tipos de Producto uno que es Unidad y otro que es Menu entonces por eso puse Producto como clase padre y Menu y Unidad como derivadas

Comment: Edité la respuesta, espero que te ayude.